# ASP.Net Ajax ComboBox Autocomplete Internet Explorer 11 Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a straight-forward Ajax ComboBox within my ASP.Net web application which is bound to an array of list items:

```
ListItem[] testItems = GetTestItems();
test.Items.AddRange(testItems);

<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="test" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" DropDownStyle="Simple" MaxLength="9999">
</ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Using Firefox, Chrome and Safari, all works as expected i.e. you start typing and the auto complete mode finds and highlights the closest match.

[image: Example in Chrome]

However, using Internet Explorer 11, you start typing and nothing happens. The list of items appears but no autocomplete or selection happens.

[image: Example Internet Explorer 11]

Does anyone know if or how this can be fixed?

Cheers
John

Answer (score 0):

What jQuery version do you use?

This **was** broken before version 1.8.2.

Comment: Thanks Margus. I'm using v1.11.1. But would that matter as the problem is with an Ajax control?